# char*-Array as Parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, parameters, function-pointers

I want to put the following code in a function: (The code isn't complete, but I think it should be clear to you)

```
char *parsedData[SEPERATOR];

for(int i=0; i<SEPERATOR; i++)
{
    parsedData[i]=tmp;
}
```

The function should look like the following:

```
int main()
{
    char *parsedData[SEPERATOR];
    Parser(WTString, parsedData);
}
int Parser(char *WTString, *parsedData[SEPERATOR])
{
    for(int i=0; i<SEPERATOR; i++)
    {
        parsedData[i]=tmp;
    }
}
```

The code works fine in one function. By dividing the code in two functions I got no usable data.

I would be grateful if someone could help me. I don't want to use further libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use stl, I propose this function:

```
int PointToDefault(char* target, char** parsedData, unsigned int count)
{
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
      parsedData[i] = target;
    }
}
```

and this call:

```
#define SEPERATOR 15
int main()
{
  char tmp[] = "default string";

  char *parsedData[SEPERATOR];
  PointToDefault(tmp, parsedData, SEPERATOR);
}
```

Comment: it shouldn't matter. if the count is a constant, what's the point of passing it?

Comment: If ever you need to use this for two strings of different lengths or in another program, you won't have to change anything in your function (if it's for work, you may have to re-test the whole function after editing it to prove it's still doing what it should). Also, following your reasoning, you could just declare the strings as global, reference them in the function hardcoded and omit all parameters, but what's the use of extracting it into a function then?

Comment: the point is, doing this makes no difference regarding the issue the question is asking

Comment: OK, but why pass the array as an argument, but define its length in the function itself? That would not be very consistent. If you are going to modularize your code, you can just as well go all the way. Of course you are right, it would work that way, but so would putting all code into `main` or using the array as a global ;)

Answer (score 1):

`char *parsedData[SEPERATOR];`  Why?

Why do you need to use a raw array of pointers to `char` in C++?

Why don't you just use a `std::vector<std::string>`  and spare yourself a whole load of misery and despair.

Answer (score 1):

A C++ way of doing it would look like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> Parser(const char *WTString)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i != SEPERATOR; ++i)
    {
        result.push_back(tmp); // whatever tmp is 
    }
    return result;
}
```

> I dont want to use further librarys.

Don't worry, my code sample only requries the standard library.